# Can't download html

Tags: java, android, html, download, jsoup

I'm trying to download this html

I'm using this code:

```
           Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc =Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
Log.i ("html", doc.toString());
```

**UPDATED:**
ASLO tried to use it:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // 
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // 
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            // 
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // 
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                str.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // 
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // 
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String html = str.toString();
        Log.e("html", html);
```

again responce like this one:

```
         <html>
<body>
<script>document.cookie="BPC=f563534535121d5a1ba5bd1e153b";
    document.location.href="http://...link.../all?attempt=1";</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't find any solution... Page can not be downloaded maybe because haven't cookie ... or what?

Comment: Need more information. "using this code" - For what? What language is that? Looks like some Javascript, but then again.. it does not.

Comment: @Snorlax java and android see tags

Comment: Yeah I get that. It still does not make sense. What do you mean by "trying to download this html" - Are you trying to display it using Java? Are you trying to download and store it on the SDCard using Java?

Comment: @Snorlax tring to download sorce of this page to String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the script tag, you have this statement :

```
document.location.href="....link..../all?attempt=1";
```

Normally it forces the browser to reload the page with the location. I think it's the page "....link...?attempt=1" that you want to download in fact.

It is not sure that it will work anyway if you don't use the cookie defined in the script but it deserves a try.

Comment: WTF is this website ! ;) Where does it go in a browser ?

Comment: Thanks for your good advice I just reconnect to link with cookie BPC=f563534535121d5a1ba5bd1e153b